# Angular2: How to put return service value into private variable object?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating an Accounting System UI and using angular2 as my framework.

My app is working except for assigning the service value into private var. I created a service to make it more dynamic.

So, here's my Service

/* formdata.ts */

```
export class Formdata {
    viewBy: string;
    companyUnit: string;
    financialYear: string;
    clients: string;
}
```

/* mocked-form */

import { Formdata } from './formdata'

```
export const FORMDATA: Formdata[] = [
    {
        viewBy: 'Daniela Oraa',
        companyUnit: 'BIR - Legazpi',
        financialYear: '2016',
        clients: 'Dummy Text 1'
    }
];
```

/* form.service.ts */

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Formdata } from './formdata';
import { FORMDATA } from './mocked-form';

@Injectable()
export class FormService {
  getData(): Promise<Formdata[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(FORMDATA);
  }
}
```

Injecting Service into Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Formdata } from '../formdata';
import { FormService } from '../form.service';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app/html-templates/clientdata_balance.html',
  styleUrls: ['css/templates.css'],
  providers: [ FormService ]
})

export class BalanceComponent implements OnInit {
    formData: Formdata[];

    constructor(private formService: FormService){}

    getData(): void {
        this.formService.getData().then(formData => this.formData = formData);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getData();
    }

    private data = this.formService.getData().then(formData => this.formData = formData);

    search_data(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
}
```

If you check the private data in component. I tried to get the data in the service. Unfortunately, no luck.

Basically, it will be a value of inputs and selecboxes.

So, here's my form

```
<form>
  <label class="input-group">
    <p>View By</p>
    <select [(ngModel)]="data.viewBy" name="viewBy">
      <option>Daniela Oraa</option>
      <option>Lovely Laparan</option>
      <option>Justin Bibo</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label class="input-group">
    <p>Company Unit</p>
    <select [(ngModel)]="data.companyUnit" name="companyUnit">
      <option>Nusa</option>
      <option>Bumi</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label class="input-group">
    <p>Financial Year</p>
    <select [(ngModel)]="data.financialYear" name="financialYear">
      <option>2016</option>
      <option>2004</option>
      <option>1945</option>
      <option>1897</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label class="input-group">
    <p>Clients</p>
    <select [(ngModel)]="data.clients" name="clients">
      <option>Dummy Text 1</option>
      <option>Dummy Text 2</option>
      <option>Dummy Text 3</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label class="input-group">
    <p>Date From</p>
    <input type="date" [(ngModel)]="data.dateFrom" name="dateFrom"/>
  </label>
  <label class="input-group">
    <p>Date To</p>
    <input type="date" [(ngModel)]="data.dateTo" name="dateTo"/>
  </label>
  <button type="button" (click)="search_data(data)">Search</button>
</form>
```

The logic I can think to put a value in ngModel data object is:

```
private data = {
  viewBy: 'Daniela Oraa',
  ...
}
```

I also tried this eventhough it I knew that it won't work.

```
private data = formData;
```

The second way is to inject value inside the element.

```
<form *ngFor="let fdata of formData">
    <select [(ngModel)]="data.viewBy" name="viewBy" [ngValue]="fdata.viewBy"> 
    // this method fail but I can get fdata.viewBy value

    ...
```

I tried all that I can think of. And none of them work. So, I decided to ask it here in SO.

Any help would mean so much to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation inside the code.

In your component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Formdata } from '../formdata';
import { FormService } from '../form.service';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app/html-templates/clientdata_balance.html',
  styleUrls: ['css/templates.css'],
  providers: [ FormService ]
})

export class BalanceComponent implements OnInit {
    formData: Formdata[];
    private data = {}; // prevents error property undefined

    constructor(private formService: FormService){}

    // no need to reference a function (getData) because you will use it right away

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.formService.getData().then(value => {
            // getData() from form.service.ts

            for(let i in value[0]) this.data[i] = value[0][i];
            /* Basically, this for ... in loop do the magic.
               Looping over the object

               It will be this.data[key] = value
               -- or -- for example

               this.data['viewBy'] = 'Sample 1';
               this.data['companyUnit'] = 'BIR';
               ...

            */
        })
    }

    search_data(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
}
```

Hope it works with you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

With this line

```
private data = this.formService.getData().then(formData => this.formData = formData);
```

the data (`FORM_DATA` from your service) is assigned to `this.formData`.

`this.data` only gets a reference to the promise.

Comment: this seems like a good place to ask instead of opening new question. I am doing the same thing as OP and i was surprised by the fact that you should create your own model FormData (according to official documentation and their Hero example) but what it ends up is overwriting private field (of type FormData) with whatever the response from the server is instead of mapping it. They don't even show mapping as an option. So the question is, should we really just overwrite local FormData with server response or should mapping be implemented manually?

Comment: What do you mean by "mapping"?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that doesn't work with me. I believe that Promises are asynchronous. So, I can't call it anywhere. But I run simple test calling this.data and return me this __zone_symbol__value which has the value of my data from service.

Comment: by mapping i mean assigning values properties of servers response object to the properties of private instance of class of type FormData. otherwise, our view (bindings in template) end up tightly-coupled to whatever servers model design is (property names, uppercase/lowercase, etc) and change of the property name on the server would break the view.
or, if you put it the other way...why would you define private object formData : FormData[] and not formData : any, since you'll overwrite it with server response anyways?

Comment: You can call `.then(...)` on the promise assigned to `this.data` to get the data but you are already doing this anyway. Calling `.then(...)` on a promise returns a promise. and `formData => this.formData = formData` returns `formData`, so the resulting promise is the same you get from `this.formService.getData()`.

Comment: @deezg Sorry, but I still don't understand. Perhaps you mean not assigning the whole object but each property on it's own to be able to cope with differences of the model on client and server. I don't see how this is related to Angular2. The Angular2 docs show how to use Angular2. If I understand you correctly this is an architectural decision IMHO entirely outside of Angulars scope.

Comment: yes, you are understanding correctly. it is about mapping properties (each) from servers response object to local formData (in this example) object. and yes, i agree mapping itself is architectural decision outside of Angular scope, but i was just confused with examples in docs (and practice here) that first they declare formData: FormData and then they overwrite it with server response (which might but doesn't have to at all be like FormData). In my mind, declaring formData: FormData would imply mapping as neccessary, and declaring formData:any would imply overwrite with servers response.

Comment: The type in `formData:FormData` is just for static analysis and and autocompletion. There are no type checks at runtime. This is still JS land and you have to take care of such stuff yourself. This is why I use Dart ;-) Dart finally transpiles to JS as well but it has a development mode where type information is compiled into JS and types are checked at runtime as well. Only for deployment type information is removed for performance reasons.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I created a function setData which returns this.formData. but if I console.log it inside ngOnInit. It will return undefined. If I console.log it inside search_data which is click event. It return the object data. So, it might be async problem. I resolve async in post ajax before but I don't know how to do it in promises. :/

Comment: @user111111 You always need to chain async calls with `then(...)` or `map(...)` or similar. If you do an async call like `someAsyncCall(result => this.data = result); console.log(this.data)` console log is executed before the async call is actually done because `console.log(this.data)` is not chained. `result => this.data = result` is a function you pass to the observable. It is not executed immediately. It is called by the observable when it emits data.

Comment: @Günter of course that it being js land explains why it works, it was just a question of good habits :) it feels like they are introducing bad habits with such examples where you should first define a strong type and then ignore it. or maybe its just me being the same person creating those same types in server response in C# :)
thanks for your considerations, anyways. really appreciate it!

Comment: Most Angular2 users come from JS and if they don't also have a strong background from strongly typed languages like C# or Java they have a hard time to understand why one needs types at all, which are verbose, cumbersome and mainly noise... So the Angular2 team has to compromise to address all people with their docs ...

Comment: @user111111 the fact you see object on click is only due to the circumstance that your clicking takes more time than Promise to resolve. that is exact purpose of Promises: for you to be able to go on with things (consol.log, for example) before your async function resolves.

Comment: @deezg Why you shouldn't answer my question? I should've choose your answer. Actually, you don't give me answer but I understand now how to do it. You gave me the hint. Thanks man. And also to Gunter. :)